# C++ ImGui - Display a Gif or Video?

Tags: c++, video, gif, mp4, imgui

I am currently coding a winrate statistics menu for League of Legends (which got approved) using ImGui and I wonder if it is possible to display a GIF or MP4 on the Menu as a Preview or Usage Tutorial not from File/Memory but from an URL as I want to keep the File as small as possible for now.

You probably would have to use a filestream, downloading the file to tmp and then displaying it as a Texture?

I found a similar question, and I wonder if something since then has changed:
https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/2680

Is it still required to use an additional GIF loader?
Are there any easy ways now to achieve that?

I am a bit (new) to ImGui and would be very happy about any reference source code (not to copy paste, just to learn it).

Thanks for any help :).